# afnetworking post can't sent param

Tags: php, ios

my code in xcode:

```
> NSDictionary *param = @{@"username":
> self.username.text,@"password":self.password.text};
>     NSString *urlString = @"http://dwjdwj.cn/index.php";
>     NSLog(@"%@",param);
>     AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
>     manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
>     manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
>     manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json",
> @"text/javascript",@"text/html",nil];
>     [manager POST:urlString parameters:param progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable
> responseObject) {
>         NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>         NSLog(@"%@",string);
>     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
>         NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
>     }];
```

my code in server:

```
> $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123");     if (!$con)
>   {     die('连接失败: ' . mysql_error());    }   else    {
>       $username=isset($_POST['username'])?$_POST['username']:false;
>       $password=isset($_POST['password'])?$_POST['password']:false;       echo
> "username = ".$username;      echo "password = ".$password;
>       $db_selected = mysql_select_db("app", $con);        $check_query =
> mysql_query("select * from user where username='$username' and
> password='$password' limit 1");       if ($result =
> mysql_fetch_array($check_query)) {            echo "log success";         }else{
>           echo "log failure";         }       mysql_close($con);  }
```

and my xcode console log:

```
HttpDemo[23512:4507807] username = password = log failure
```

It seem the php can't get the post param. Do I did something wrong?

Comment: pls format the code to a good style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the request as a form set the requestSerializer to `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`. The `AFJSONRequestSerializer` sets the content-type to `application/json`.

If you actually need the exchange to be in JSON then on your server you should read it like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('some url');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: What can i do in my php to fit the json post?Anyway thank you.

Comment: Do you actually need JSON? If you just need to post the data as you have shown simply send the `NSDictionary` as the `parameters` parameter, like you are doing already and you should be able to read them as a form.